# NSPersistentContainer equivalent for NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore ofType and options

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, ios10

At WWDC2016 Apple introduces `NSPersistentContainer` for iOS10

The **NSPersistentContainer** class is in charge of loading the data model, creating a managed object model, and using it to create a **NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.**

Its initialization is really easy:

```swift
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "myContainerName")
container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { /* ... handles the error ... */ })
```

Previously in the CoreData stack creation we set up the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` adding a PersistentStore in particular with "ofType" and "storeOptions"

```swift
let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: [NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey:FileProtectionType.complete, NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true] as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

using in this case

`NSSQLiteStoreType` for *ofType*  parameter

and

`[NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey:FileProtectionType.complete, NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true]`
for *options*  parameter

How can I configure this kind of stuff using `NSPersistentContainer`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
description.setOption(FileProtectionType.complete, forKey: NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey)
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
```

Comment: You should get the URL of the persister though to create your store description:
let storeURL = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url!
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)

Comment: The compiler complained about `FileProtectionType.complete` and asked me to cast to `NSObject`

Is this OK?


`description.setOption(FileProtectionType.complete as NSObject, forKey: NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey)`

Answer (score 4):

(Posting a separate answer since it's too long to be a comment on the last answer)

The following code worked for me:

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")

let storeDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let url = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyApp.sqlite")
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
description.setOption(FileProtectionType.completeUnlessOpen as NSObject, forKey: NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey)
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in ... }
```